# Can't add overflow-x to container of floats

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I want to add horizontal scroll-bar to footer, when there is not enough space for divs, but instead that it just drops to lower line.

I added

```css
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but it still doesn't work.
How should fix it?

```css
footer {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
footer #items {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}
footer #items div {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: left;
  height: 134px;
  width: 134px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #752b01;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="items">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: For me, the items divs just go beneath each other. So no scrollbar there.

Comment: @ChrisG That's the problem, precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inline-blocks instead of floats, and prevent line breaks:

```css
#items {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#items div {
  float: none;
}
```

```css
footer {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#items {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#items div {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  height: 134px;
  width: 134px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #752b01;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="items">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use floats, you will need

```css
#items {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```css
footer {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#items {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
#items div {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  height: 134px;
  width: 134px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #752b01;
  border-width: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="items">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

But note some browsers require vendor extensions and others don't support it yet.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!